# Android video real time filtering

Tags: java, android, android-mediacodec

I am writing a video player where I try to apply a filter on each decoded frame before showing it on the screen.

I use `MediaCodec` to extract a frame. The frames are decoded to a Surface created from `SurfaceTexture`, rendered (off-screen) into a pbuffer, extracted with `glReadPixels()`

I have used the **ExtractMpegFramesTest** as an example from this page:

http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

At this point I have `ByteBuffer` with the extracted pixels, on which I do some post processing (converting to *grayscale*, or running edge detection etc.)

Having done that, I want to render the filtered frame on the screen.
I could again encode it with the MediaCodec and use a VideoView to render it, but that way each frame is encoded and decoded unnecesarryly.

Is there an efficient way to render these frames on the screen?

Comment: I am working on the same, can you help me how you did it?

Comment: @SanjayHirani Check out ExtractMpegFramesTest at http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/. I use a modified version of the CodecOutputSurface class from this example. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: upload the pixels to a GLES texture, using `glTexImage2D()`, and render a quad.

Depending on your filtering, you may also want to consider performing the operations entirely in GLES.  This is significantly faster, but a bit harder to pull off because the filters must be written in the fragment shader (GLSL).

You can find an example of shader-based image filtering in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) ([demo video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg)), along with some uses of `glTexImage2D()` to send bitmap data to a texture.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed!